# using the combo box in gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, combobox

I have a problem with binding a combo box with rad grid view in windows forms.

My problem is that I have a combo box with the items as (`border styles-solid, double, groove, dotted, etc`); in the selected change event of combo box I should change the border of grid view elements. How can I do this?.

My code is

```
comboBox.SelectedItem = radGridView.TableElement;
```

My code doesn't generate an error but when run, my grid view border style is not changing.

In the properties window also, for event settings i have assigned `comboBox_SelectionChanged` event with selection Change event.

Comment: Do you have a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` or is there any other ComboBox on your Form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grid view combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446825/grid-view-combobox)